# How do I convert this SQL outer join to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

I want to convert this to Linq:

```
SELECT      {fields}
FROM        tableA AS A
LEFT JOIN   tableB AS B
ON             B.Field1 = MyVariable
AND            (    A.Key = B.Key
               OR   A.Key = B.AlternateKey)
```

It's that OR in conjunction with the AND clause that is tripping me over.

EDIT: Can I have the solution as extension methods please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from a in tableA
  from b in tableB.Where(b => b.Field1 == MyVariable && (a.Key == b.Key || a.Key == b.AlternateKey)).DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new { a, b };

tableA.SelectMany(
  a => tableB.Where(b => b.Field1 == MyVariable && (a.Key == b.Key || a.Key == b.AlternateKey)).DefaultIfEmpty()
  .Select(b => new { a, b })
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, can I have that as Extension Methods?